# Ending a reaction game Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the related link: http://jsbin.com/cebisoqovo/edit?html,output

I just started on code learning and recently created a game called *Reaction Tester* with my limited knowledge. However, I am faced with a minor problem at the end.

***Question:***

So whenever there is random square or circle shown, all you have to do is click and the time taken to click & the point will be shown on the right side. However, I do not know how to set the ending time of the game and it just keeps continuously popping out the shapes. I have the try again and result (under css) set as display:none in order to only have these popped out at the end of the game. However, i do not know how to end it. Please help! Thank you!

p/s: There was something wrong with the insertion of code directly here. If it's okay for you, please go to the jsbin link and copy the code and paste on your respective application to have a better look at it since jsbin isn't really showing it clearly. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Your jsbin is hard to view, maybe add a little code to the question also?

Comment: Hi! I am sorry for the trouble. Let me put the code here so it will be more convenient for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a global variable named gameRunning, set it to true. create a timeout function set for 30 seconds that sets gameRunning to false. In your function that creates shapes, first check if gameRunning is true. If gameRunning is true, then create shapes as normal. If gameRunning is false, then do nothing.

^ the above solution works, but you would get 1 last box created after the game has ended because of the way boxes are created.

https://jsfiddle.net/vmo5x2vz/3/

After working with it for a while, I found a different and better way of doing it for your particular situation.

I create a global variable named makeBoxTO, the 'TO' meaning timeout.

```
var makeBoxTO;
```

Then I assign the timeout found in makeBox() to this makeBoxTO variable. This is so that we can refer to that timeout outside of the makeBox() function.

```
makeBoxTO = setTimeout(function()...
```

Then I set a 10 second timer to end the game.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  clearTimeout(makeBoxTO);
  document.getElementById("Box").style.display = "none";
  alert('game over');
},10000);
```

It clears our makeBox timeout, hides any box's on screen, and lets the user know the game is over.

Comment: I am sorry but do you mind elaborate more about it? I am new to Javascript so I am still currently learning! Hope to hear from you soon and thanks in advance!

Comment: James, did you see the update to answer? I don't know if SO sends a message when an answer has been updated or not.

Comment: Hey I got to see the update. Thank you so much for your help and taking the time to solve my problem. Really appreciate it. I already voted your answer as the best. Please let me know what else I could do to help increasing your reputation if you wish as I am a new member here. Thanks again!

Comment: @JamesLee You're welcome. I think you can up-vote it by clicking the up arrow to the left of the answer. I'm not really in it for reputation, but it is fun to see the number go up, like a video game. :)